# How to convert elements in a nested array to an array of objects with name and value properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

Say for example I have this nested array :

```
{
    "name": "Central",
    "children": [
        {
            "Cellophane Tape": 79.7194,
            "File Separator": 64.0017,
            "Hard Cover File": 23.2734,
            "Highlighter": 67.2899,
            "Office Chair": 74.2509,
            "Pencil": 74.2509,
            "Tape Dispenser": 67.2899,
            "File Cabinet": 21.058,
            "Plastic Comb Binding": 74.2509,
            "White Board Markers": 74.2509,
            "Binder": 67.2899,
            "Eraser": 64.0017
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to map it to become like this :

```
{
    "name": "Central",
    "children": [
        {
            {"name" : "Cellophane Tape","value":79.7194},
            {"name" : "File Separator","value":64.0017},
            {"name" : "Hard Cover File","value":23.2734},
            {"name" : "Highlighter", "value":67.2899},
            {"name" : "Office Chair","value":74.2509},
            {"name" : "Pencil","value": 74.2509},
            {"name" : "Tape Dispenser","value" : 67.2899},
            {"name" : "File Cabinet","value": 21.058},
            {"name" : "Plastic Comb Binding","value": 74.2509},
            {"name" : "White Board Markers","value": 74.2509},
            {"name" : "Binder","value" : 67.2899},
            {"name" : "Eraser","value": 64.0017}
        }
    ]
}
```

This nested array is the result of me aggregating all my values inside the leaf nodes of my tree using this code. If I could put the name and value properties inside this algorithm, would be nice. I tried to replace `[o.name] : o.value` to `"name":[o.name],"value":o.value` but it only adds it once and not for every element in the array.

```
  function aggDeep(obj) {
  let hasChildren = o => o.children && o.children.length,
    hasNoChildren = o => !(o.children && o.children.length),
    map = {},
    aggDeepRec = ({
      name,
      children
    }, res = []) => {
      if (hasChildren({
          children
        })) {
        let leafs = children.filter(hasNoChildren).map(o => ({
          [o.name]: o.value
        }))
        if (leafs.length) {
          let childArray = (map[name] = map[name] || []);
          childArray.push(Object.assign(...leafs));
          res.push({
            name,
            children: childArray
          })
        }
        children.filter(hasChildren).forEach(c => aggDeepRec(c, res));
      }
      return res;
    }
  return aggDeepRec(obj);
}
```

A solution independent of this algorithm is also accepted.

**Full data** : https://api.myjson.com/bins/obdj0

Comment: You cannot have duplicate key `name` and `value` in same object. Keys must be unique

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal My bad. forgot to add the curly braces. They are separate objects.

Comment: It is still incorrect. Please confirm that. Also let us know if there is only one object in `children` array that needs to be converted?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal A link to my full data is provided. Confirm what? Please specify what is incorrect with my question. Nope. I want to convert every element in the children array to its own object with the "name" and "value" properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution which came to my mind is to convert the children object to an array first, then create your custom object with mapping through it, but this will give you an array of object with "name" and "value" properties, I hope can help :

```
const mainObject = {
"name": "Central",
"children": [
    {
        "Cellophane `Tape": 10.528979999999999,
        "Cellophane Tape": 79.7194,
        "File Separator": 64.0017,
        "Hard Cover File": 23.2734,
        "Highlighter": 67.2899,
        "Office Chair": 74.2509,
        "Pencil": 74.2509,
        "Tape Dispenser": 67.2899,
        "File Cabinet": 21.058,
        "Plastic Comb Binding": 74.2509,
        "White Board Markers": 74.2509,
        "Binder": 67.2899,
        "Eraser": 64.0017
    }
]
}

let obj = mainObject.children[0]

var arr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push(key + '=' + obj[key]);
    }
};
let newArray = []
arr.map(item => {
    newArray.push({"name": item.substr(0, item.indexOf('=')),
     "value": item.substr(item.indexOf('=')+1, item.length) })
})
let result = {
  "name" : mainObject.name,
  "children" : newArray
 }
 console.log(result)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/n0z18g5v/1/

This going to give you something like this :

[image]

**UPDATE :**

I Update the solution based on your full-data :

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/n0z18g5v/10/

Comment: Updated my question with a link to the full data. Can you edit your answer to fit it in?

Comment: @SyedAriff I update the solution based on your full data

Comment: What happened to the root node "children"? In my JSON data, the highest level node in it is "children". However , in your result array , that root node seem to be gone.Great work btw.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you making an array for a single object element but considering your structure this is how you can convert the array

```
let allKeys = Object.keys(yourInitialObject.children[0])
allKeys.map(key => { 
  return { name: key, value: yourInitialObject.children[0][key] } 
})
yourInitialObject.children = allKeys
```

Comment: Please refer to full data and not the sample data that I posted. Updated my question.